# Accessing a subclass attribute from parent's class method

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance

I'm trying to make the idea behind the code below work, that is, to have a parent class that defines a bunch of methods that use `__class__` access static attributes with those attributes defined in the subclasses. However my naive attempt will raise an AttributeError because when I call `son.fun()` it looks for `bar` in `Parent`. `Parent` would never need to be instantiated by itself and it doesn't need to support diamond inheritance patterns.

```py
class Parent:    
    def fun(self):
        print(__class__.bar)
    
class Daughter(Parent):
    bar = 2.71

class Son(Parent):
    bar = 3.14
    

daughter = Daughter()
son = Son()

son.fun()  # AttributeError: type object 'Parent' has no attribute 'bar'
```

In my codebase I have two classes that look like `Daughter` and `Son` which have their own version of `fun`. Something like:

```py
class Daughter:
    bar = 2.71

    def fun(self):
        print(__class__.bar)

class Son:
    bar = 3.14

    def fun(self):
        print(__class__.bar)

daughter = Daughter()
son = Son()

son.fun()  # All good
```

That works but it introduces a lot of code duplication which will only increase as I add more classes. The current implementation requires me to modify all the classes each time I want to tweak `fun` and I feel there must be a better way.

I have thought of modifying `Parent` by adding the attributes defined in `Son` and `Daughter` when they are instantiated so that `__class__.bar` works but I'm not sure on how to go about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the `__class__` attribute via `self` - which will resolve to the `Son` class & fetch the attribute:

```
class Parent:
    def fun(self):
        print(self.__class__.bar)


class Daughter(Parent):
    bar = 2.71


class Son(Parent):
    bar = 3.14


daughter = Daughter()
son = Son()

son.fun()
daughter.fun()
```

Prints:

```
3.14
2.71
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> class Parent:
    def fun(self):
        print(__class__.bar)
...
>>> class Son(Parent):
    bar = 3.14
...
>>> son = Son()
>>> son.__dict__
{}
>>> Son.__dict__
mappingproxy({'__module__': '__main__', 'bar': 3.14, '__doc__': None})
>>> son.__class__ is Son
True
>>> Parent.__dict__
mappingproxy({'__module__': '__main__', 'fun': <function Parent.fun at 0x102483dc0>, '__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'Parent' objects>, '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'Parent' objects>, '__doc__': None})
>>>
```

Class instances have `__dict__` attribute which stores attributes of the instance.

When you do `son.bar`, Python tries to find attribute `bar` in `son.__dict__`. If it's not found there, it looks into `son.__class__.__dict__`. If it's not found there, it tries to find the attribute in parents' `__dict__`s.